# v12.0 folder not found in MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I am setting up Jenkins with MSBuild.  I was getting the below error while building through jenkins

> MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found

So I downloaded and installed the MSBuild from the below URL.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40760

But it's does not contain v12.0  folder . What should i need to do here ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the *Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated)* package from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/ to get the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file to build your project.

Comment: Hi @seangrieve the download has been removed do you know any mirror link. It without this the only way left is to install whole Visual studio.

Comment: This worked for me.  I'm running VStudio 2013, but oddly I could only install the [Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell (en-US)] choice (from the link in the answer).  Once I installed that (and it is quite a large install) then I could build the web project properly.  There seems to have been an update that caused this because I was able to build previous to this on the same machine. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do. Open your build definition and go to the "Process" page. Then under the "3. Advanced" group you have a property called "MSBuild Arguments". Place the parameter there with the following syntax

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

If you have more parameters, separate them with a space and not a comma.

[image]

Comment: What does this parameter mean to build job ?